# audio streaming not playing on setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

Here is MainActivity.java

```
lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] links = res.getStringArray(R.array.links);
    String url = links[position];
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.start();

}});
```

I need to play the data sources placed in my String-array.
like that:

```
<string-array name="links">
    <item>http://210.56.24.230:8006/</item>
    <item>http://210.56.24.230:8044/</item>
    <item>http://210.56.24.230:8034/</item>
</string-array>
```

But the problem here is:

- I cant hear any audio. Maybe its not playing.
- There are three links each to be played when the specific list item is selected. Am i doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The Below code is working fine in my previous Project you can try this way!

```
 public static MediaPlayer mp;
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            try {

                if(mp==null){
                    mp= new MediaPlayer();
                }else{
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                    }
                }
                //Strat Loading
                mp.setDataSource(CarsActivity.this,
                        Uri.parse(getResources().getStringArray(R.id.arr)[position]));

                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        //Dismiss Loading
                    }
                });
                mp.prepareAsync();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }});
   }
```

Comment: How can this work with list items? Can you please elaborate .

Comment: can you tell me what should i write in place of your CarsActivity.this? @Intsab

Comment: By writing MainActivity.this or (R.array.arr)*

Comment: Still its not playing anything .